# Get total no. of followers of specific account on instagram

Tags: php, api, instagram

I want to track total followers that's I'm getting each day, for that I want to get total no. of followers digit.
Any one have idea which API of Instagram can help me with this or any other idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

use this API:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

this will give you counts for followers, following.

https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users